# SQL Server 2005 Database move and rationalisation - Recommended maintenance processes

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, migration

We're moving a SQL Server 2005 database to a new server and upgrading to 2008, and I'm looking for some advice and reassurance that our approach is correct.

I inherited this database and it came to me in a bit of a mess truth be told - on top of that I've basically learnt to be a SQL Server developer on this server (no educational background in computing) so I've made plenty of my own mistakes on it. We're underfunded as a department (public sector), and so lacking expertise, pulling ourselves up by our bootstrings. The database started out as a back room thing but has become very important to our organisation and given this the performance is frankly embarrassing.

So we have issues such as

- history of Autoshrink usage
- History of undersized storage - never really enough space on the server for the db to grow so I'd guess the files are probably quite internally fragmented.
- There are multiple collation types (for no good reason),
- Inappropriate `text` datatypes all over the place (lots of `Nvarchar`, `nchar`, `ntext` when we have no need of ascii characters, and `text` where `varchar` would be more appropriate)

The new server is a 64bit virtual server, storage on RAID.

My plan after installing and upgrading is to:

- Remove a vast amount of tables we've identified (with confidence) as redundant (about 1/3 of db size!)
- Normalise collations to 1 type (after some analysis and testing we're certain this won't cause us problems - we have no requirement for case sensitivity)
- Normalise `text` data types to `varchar`/`char`
- Set database file sizes to the expected usage for the coming 2 years plus 50%

Is there anything else I should be considering after/before these processes - and do any of decisions here look off mark? For example the file size issue - is this something I need to worry about on RAID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Shrinking and Storage**

Enable "Instant File Initialization"

Disable autoshrink

Size your storage properly (15% free per drive)

RAID what? [RAID level matters](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/Cc966414#_RAID) and SQL Server accesses the files differently. Log file access is generally sequential and Data is generally random.

**tempdb**

Separate data and log files (see RAID, below) - get a good `tempdb` strategy. We have `tempdb` logs on a log drive and our `tempdb` files (1/4-1/2 the number of cores) on their own drive. While you're at it, make sure that `tempdb` has an appropriate number of data files, that their initial sizing is exactly the same, and that they have exactly the same growth factor. While you're at it, read up on [Trace Flag 1118](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/misconceptions-around-tf-1118/)

**Schema Changes**

If you're going to be making these changes, make sure you have a good, durable backup. What happens in 9 months when someone actually needed those tables?

Can your application actually withstand the changes from `NVARCHAR`, `NCHAR`, and `NTEXT`? While you're at it, `NTEXT` is deprecated so moving to `TEXT` would not be good. Check out `VARBINARY` or `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead.

You can change the collation all you want, but it won't affect any of the existing data.

**Compatibility**

Change the db compatibility levels to 100 if you can.

**Tuning Option**

Check out some of these [trace flags](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920093) none of them may be appropriate. Some of them might be, "it depends." Also, read about trace flag 4199.

**Tooling**

I'd also recommend coming in to this install with a good tool set. Create a `DBA` database for this toolkit. I'd start with `sp_WhoIsActive` by Adam Machanic, `sp_Blitz` by Brent Ozar. I'd also look for Kendra Little's work with scheduling and storing the results from `sp_WhoIsActive`. Finally, I'd start up a way of capturing [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/Cc966413) so that you have a good history of your server's profile.

Look into getting a monitoring solution.

Finally (and maybe firstly), check out Glenn Berry's excellent series on provisioning a new SQL Server Instance.

[Part 1](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/provisioning-a-new-sql-server-instance-%E2%80%93-part-one/), [Part 2](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/provisioning-a-new-sql-server-instance-%E2%80%93-part-two/), and [Part 3](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/provisioning-a-new-sql-server-instance-%E2%80%93-part-three/)

Comment: This is superb, thanks very much. Autoshrink is long since turned off, but the rest of this is going to be fantastically helpful. We have little direct control over our hardware, but I'll bring the provisioning issues up in discussion with our server team.

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad you have an opportunity to do this cleanup. I wouldn't worry too much about setting the database file sizes. As long as you have enough disk space, SQL Server can fly itself in this regard

In general, however, your issues shouldn't be impacting performance and that may still be an issue after cleanup. The solution would be to find and improve long-running queries. You can use SQL Server Profiler to find the problem queries, and I learned a lot by breaking them down and running them in SQL Server Management Studio, looking at execution times and execution plans. Good luck!

Comment: thanks! We're planning to make better use of profiler after the move. At the moment the db performs so badly we've been concerned that the overhead of profiler would just make life impossible.

Comment: Yes, I'd wait until after the move.  You don't leave the profiler running, incidentally, you just use it to collect a sample of the activity for a little while.  As little as ten minutes, if there's enough activity for your slow queries to show up in that sample.

Comment: thanks, that's good to know. - I anticipated running it over a week or so to capture representative use; but you'd recommend not?

Comment: I'd certainly start with a small sample and play around with the slow queries you pick up.  You will want a larger sample if you want to run the trace through the Database Engine Tuning Advisor and actually believe its index recommendation (I hesitate about that - indexing is often a case of less-is-more and common sense).  The other case where I've run Profiler for a day or longer is when I'm trying to catch some rare condition.  Also consider using PerfMon, if these are CPU/memory/disk bottlenecks.  But I'd focus on the slow queries first.

Comment: Another thought: these performance issues won't differ greatly between SQL Server 2005 and 2008 (though 64 bits and new hardware will help). Do you have a test environment? If not, you might keep your old server around as a test environment to try out ideas (e.g., does adding an index really help this query?) Or else set up a parallel test database on the new server, if you have the disk space for it. You definitely need a test space of some sort.

Comment: Thanks very much for all this - incredibly helpful stuff and very much appreciated. A test server is maybe a possibility now. I've certainly felt the inability to test tuning options somewhere safe- as have our users occasionally!